# Can we access latitude and longitude values from getCurrentPosition() in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, location, latitude-longitude

I want to show weather based on User's current location on screen loading. I do get the current location, I even get the weather info based on it,but, the problem is I can't render it on screen. All trials done, but, all in vain

Following is the piece of code
App.js in componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        const lat = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
        const lon = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
        console.log('Lat', lat)
        console.log('Lon', lon)
        this.fetchWeather(position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude);
      },
      (error) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error))},
      {
        enabledHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 50000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      })

}
```

Outside componentDidMount()

```
fetchWeather = async (lat, lon) => {
    const weather = await fetch(`${api}lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&key=${API_KEY3}`);
    const result = await weather.json();
      this.setState({
        city: result.data[0].city_name,
        country: result.data[0].country_code,
        humidity: result.data[0].rh,
        temperature: result.data[0].temp,
        wind: result.data[0].wind_spd,
        humidity: result.data[0].rh,
        description: result.data[0].weather.description, 
      });
      console.log('DATA', this.state)
    }
```

In 'DATA' I'am getting total data but, unable to render it on screen

How to retrieve lat and lon values from getCurrentPosition() outside this method?
I want to use longitude and latitude values outside the method

Comment: why are you unable to render the data? The state has the correct values, right?

Comment: Can you post your render function?

Comment: Thanks fo the reply... I would post render function shortly, but, I want to retrieve latitude and longitude values from getCurrentPosition(), can we do it?